# I need the program to ask the user for numbers and then it finds the maxium and minimum of the three

Tags: java

I have the code here but I'm having problems with it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please input 3 integers: ");
    int w = Integer.parseInt(keyboard.nextLine());
    int a = Integer.parseInt(keyboard.nextLine());
    int s = Integer.parseInt(keyboard.nextLine());
    int max = Math.max(w, a);
    if (max > a) {
        max = Math.max(a, s);
        max = Math.max(a, s);
        int min = Math.min(w, a);
        if (min > a) {
            min = Math.min(a, s);
            min = Math.min(a, s);
        }
    } else {
        max = Math.max(a, s);
    }
    System.out.println("The max of three is: " + max);
    System.out.println("the minimum of the three is: " + min);
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem?  Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int maximum = Math.max(w, Math.max(a, s));
int minimum = Math.min(w, Math.min(a, s));
```

Answer (score 1):

Notice that you don't need to read line and then parse it into integer. You can use scanner.nextInt() method. With that in mind your program would look as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n1 = scanner.nextInt();
    int n2 = scanner.nextInt();
    int n3 = scanner.nextInt();

    int max = Math.max(n1, n2);
    max = Math.max(max, n3);
    System.out.println("Max: " + max);      


    int min = Math.min(n1, n2);
    min = Math.min(min, n3);
    System.out.println("Min: " + min);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not really the programming that needs to be improved here, it's the thinking.

So let's start with "w".  Once you've that in, you know that's the current maximum and minimum number.

so right off the bat.  You can declare max = w and min = w.

That way you have your starting point.  The rest of the exercise is in figuring out if the remaining numbers can beat "w" as the maximum or minimum.

So next, compare "a" with the current maximum which is stored in "max".  Which one is the maximum?
max = Math.max(max, a);

If it was "a", max will become "a".  If a is less than the current max, max will stay the same.

Now you can do the same with "s".
max = Math.max(max, s);

And now that you've gone through all the inputs you have, what you have left is the maximum value.  You can print out the variable "max" and you're done.

Do the exact same for minimum and you'll have your minimum values too.

The programming answers given by the other are the correct way, I hope this explains the process as to why those are the good ways to do it.

Think about each step and how you want to get there.  Break it apart into manageable steps, like finding the maximum and then finding the minimum.  You don't have to try to figure it out all at once.  Once you figure it out for each, you can easily start to combine them into something more efficient like what @Michael provided.

But the first key is to understand why, rather than how.